# java Makefile issue

Tags: java, file, makefile, javac

For a homework assignment I have to make a makefile (physically and in software) for a series of .java files that I have written.

I have written up a make file:

```
JFLAGS = -d -g bin/
JC = javac

.SUFFXES: .java .class

CLASSES = \
    cdn\communications\CommandReader.java \
    cdn\communications\CommandReaderFactory.java \
    cdn\communications\CommandReaderThread.java \
    cdn\communications\DiscoveryCommandReader.java \
    cdn\communications\Link.java \
    cdn\communications\RefreshThread.java \
    cdn\communications\RouterCommandReader.java \
    cdn\node\Discovery.java \
    cdn\node\Node.java \
    cdn\node\Router.java \
    cdn\utility\Utility.java \
    cdn\wireformats\DeRegisterRequest.java \
    cdn\wireformats\DeRegisterResponse.java \
    cdn\wireformats\LinkInfo.java \
    cdn\wireformats\LinkWeightUpdate.java \
    cdn\wireformats\MessageType.java \
    cdn\wireformats\PeerRouterList.java \
    cdn\wireformats\RegisterRequest.java \
    cdn\wireformats\RegisterResponse.java \
    cdn\wireformats\RouterInfo.java \
    cdn\wireformats\WireFormatFactory.java \

all : $(CLASSES)

clean : $(CLASSES:.java=.class)
```

But when I run it I get the message "make: Nothing to be done for `all'." and none of my files are made.

Is there something I'm missing here? I'm running the file from the directory that holds the "cdn" directory hierarchy?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: There's an `I` missing from `.SUFFIXES` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your `all` target to depend on .class files instead of .java files (that are already exist and thus " Nothing to be done").

```
all : $(CLASSES:.java=.class)
```

Also, you have to a add a rule to compile .java files into .class files:

```
%.class : %.java
    $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $<
```

In case of using the rule above (so-called [pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules)), `.SUFFXES:` isn't needed anymore, you can remove it at all.

Comment: This helped me a great deal. I ended up using something similar for clean as well.

Answer (score 2):

You have not specified how to build the java classes in your Makefile.  Essentially something like below...

```
.java.class:
        $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java
```

Refer to [this link](http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/javamakefiles.html) which has a good example.

Comment: The same goes for `clean`: it needs a recipe to `rm` the files in question.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am saving it for later.

Answer (score 0):

As outlined by others above, you can easily do something like this:

```
%.class : %.java
  javac flags_go_here
```

... but there's a few problems with this:

- If there are any dependencies between classes -- and there will be -- you'll have to get the order right.  There aren't any tools or command-line options like what GCC provides for generating dependencies for you
- Java allows circular dependencies between classes.  It isn't possible to compile two classes that depend on each-other unless you compile them together, eg:

  - ${JAVAC} ${FLAGS} class1.java class2.java
- `javac` has a long start-up time.  For small projects you won't notice it, but for any project where there's enough classes it'll add up fast, and your build times go downhill fast.

The best solution I've come up with is something like the following (using GNU-make style syntax):

```
all: my.jar

my.jar : c1.java c2.java ... cN.java
  ${JAVAC} ${JAVAC_FLAGS} ${^}
  ${JAR} cf ${JAR_FLAGS} ${@} -C src ${^:%.java=%.class}

# As a bonus, here's how you could do JNI stuff based on individual class files.
# This is necessary because nothing in the build actually depends directly on
# the .class files; if they don't exist and the .jar does, then you need some
# way to get the .class files without rebuilding the jar.

# It's written this way so it's re-usable.
# I'm using 'unzip' instead of 'jar' because it has the -j option so it won't
# dump some/irritating/path/to/work/with/when/all/I/need/is/the/.class/file
define CANNED_JAVAH_TARGET =
$(if $(filter %.java,${^}),,\
  $(error When building ${@}: No jar dependency provided))
unzip -j -d /somewhere/to/put/temp/class/file \
  $(filter %.jar,${^}) ${PKG_PATH}/${@F:%.h=%.class}
${JAVAH} ${JAVAH_FLAGS} <whatever flags are needed to make the header>
endef

${JNI_HEADER_TARGETS} : my.jar
  ${CANNED_JAVAH_TARGET}
```

There is a problem with the javah portion: for the JAVAH thing, if someone makes it depend on more than one jar, it'll break.  There may be a few minor mistakes or things to work around in the above (going from memory here), but all in all it has worked for me without much hassle.